# call function when selected value changed with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have two select and the second depends from the first
I want use knockout for check if the first selected value change, call a function that with a ajax-call populate the second select.
the first select is populated server side

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function FilterModel() {
            this.Datevalue = ko.observable();

            this.addSecond = function() {
                   ---
            }

        }

        $(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new FilterModel());
        });
    });
```

html

```
<select id="fisrt" data-bind="value: Datevalue" ></select>
<select id="second" ></select>
```

how can i call function addSecond ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed boolean to verify the `Datevalue` and use the `visible:` binding to show the second `<select>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/t8gxv/

For calling `addSecond` you can subscribe to the observable and call `addSecond` when the value changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/t8gxv/1/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function FilterModel() {
        var self = this;

        this.Datevalue = ko.observable();
        this.addSecond = function() {
              alert('addSecond');
        }

        // boolean for showing the second select
        this.showSecond = ko.computed(function() {
           return  this.Datevalue() == 'bar';
        }, this);

        // calling addSecond when the correct value is selected
        this.Datevalue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if(newValue == 'bar') {
              self.addSecond();   
            }
        });

        // easier even is to subscribe to the computed
        var subscription = this.showSecond.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            // if true
            if(newValue) {
              self.addSecond();   

              //only want to call addSecond once
              subscription.dispose();
            }
        });

    }

    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new FilterModel());
    });
});
```

It is also possible to subscribe to the computed and dispose the subscription so `addSecond` will only be called once:
http://jsfiddle.net/t8gxv/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
JAVASCRIPT:
this.Datevalue = ko.observable();
this.MakeSecondVisible = ko.observable(); 
this.ondropDownChange= function() {
      if(this.Datevalue() == something)
      {
            this.MakeSecondVisible = true;
      }


HTML : 

<select data-bind="value: Datevalue" onclick: ondropDownChange() > //FIRST ONE

<select data-bind="options: optionValues"  visible: MakeSecondVisible > //SECOND ONE
```